# IE10 Sending Double post requests to Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, internet-explorer, spring-mvc

I have a "Forgot Passowrd" button on my home page which works fine in Chrome but if its used in IE its sending two post calls which is generating 2 email notification being sent to user. How can I prevent this happen in IE?

AM using JDK 7, Spring-security 3.1.4, spring web mvc 3.2.4 and Hibernate 3.6.10

I see the below traffic when i capture it in Fiddler

`#  Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom

1   200 HTTPS   dc-rpalle7  /CP/forgotPassword.do   1,699   no-cache; Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 23:59:59 GMT    text/html;charset=utf-8 iexplore:45740

2   200 HTTP    Tunnel to   dc-rpalle7:443  0           iexplore:45740

3   200 HTTPS   dc-rpalle7  /CP/forgotPassword.do   1,699   no-cache; Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 23:59:59 GMT    text/html;charset=utf-8 iexplore:45740`

Here is my forgotPassword method in controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public ModelAndView forgotPassword(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        getCurrentRequestProperties().put(CurrentRequestProperties.IS_VALID_REQUEST, true);
        authorizationService.logout();
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        if (email != null && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(email)) {
            User uRecord = api.search.query(
                    User.class,
                    api.search.and().add(api.search.property("emailAddress").eq(email))
                            .add(api.search.property("locked").eq(false))).first();
            if (uRecord == null)
                mav.addObject("failedMessage", "forgot.email.invalid");
            else {
                String url = request.getRequestURL().toString().replaceFirst(request.getServletPath(), "");
                try {
                    collabSecurityService.forgotPasswordSendEmail(uRecord, url, "Reset Password Initiate");
                    mav.addObject("validMessage", "forgot.email.valid");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    mav.addObject("failedMessage", "forgot.email.error");
                }
            }
        }
        mav.addObject("notimeout", true);
        return mav;
    }
```

Here is my `collabSecurityService.forgotPasswordSendEmail(...)` method

```
public void forgotPasswordSendEmail(User user, String URL, String notification) {
    UserSecurityQuestions userSecQuestions = api.search.query(UserSecurityQuestions.class,
            api.search.property("user").eq(user)).first();
    if (userSecQuestions == null) notification = "Reset Password Error";
    EmailTemplate emailTemp = api.search.query(EmailTemplate.class, api.search.property("name").eq(notification))
            .first();
    if (emailTemp != null) {
        String body = emailTemp.getEmailBody();
        if (userSecQuestions != null && notification.equals("Reset Password Initiate")) {
            String hStr = Long.toHexString(new SecureRandom().nextLong());
            String url = URL.toString() + "/resetPassword.do?hStr=" + hStr;
            body += "<br/><br/>" + url;
            userSecQuestions.setHashString(hStr);
            long four = 14400000;
            userSecQuestions.setValidThrough(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime() + four));
            userSecQuestions.setTries(0);
        }

        IEmailMessage message = new EmailMessage();
        message.setSubject(emailTemp.getSubject());
        message.setToAddress(user.getEmailAddress());
        message.setFromAddress(emailTemp.getFromAddress());
        message.setEmailBody(body, emailTemp.getContentType());
        api.notification.sendEmailMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: We had similar problems with IE9 when submit was performed by Javascript. IE9 made two posts in that case. The decision was to use onclick="... return false;"

Comment: @Multisync Great!! It worked..Thanks you so much..:) Post it as answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had similar problems with IE9 when submit was performed by Javascript. IE9 made two posts in that case. The decision was to use onclick="... return false;"